# Regression using K-NN for prediction using matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn

I am interested to use `k-NN` method for training my datasets and then making prediction for the sample datasets. I have table (`tb`) each contains two variables of size 1X2000. Let us for the sake of simplicity,

The training data sets,   `X = tb(1:1500,1)`

```
      Y = tb(1:1500,2);     % both X and Y are training datasets
```

Now the sample test are given as,

```
             x = tb(1501:2000,1);
             y= tb(1501:2000,2);
```

Now I want to use `k-NN` method for  predicting new `y` value for given `x` value.

I have written code as below :

```
 mdl = fitcknn(X,Y,'NumNeighbors',150,'Standardize',1);
      predictedY = predict(mdl,x);

      plot(x,predictedY)
```

When I am running the code i am not getting correct result.

Based on some google search , I found that it this code is not for regression but for classification. I don't have any idea how k-NN can be used for regression. Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ClassificationKNN.fit` - it will be removed in a future release. Instead you can use `fitcknn`:

```
model = fitcknn(X,Y,'NumNeighbors',150);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But when I do this.  my prediction graph is totally wrong as compare to training datasets graph. I attached the graph with  modification in question, Please have a look and tell me what you think ?

Comment: I assumed you wanted to do a classification with KNN, but it looks like you want a regression instead. As far as I can tell, fitcknn can only do classification and is therefore not what you want. Unfortunately It also seems like there is no regression version of it ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807294/knn-regression-in-matlab ). So either code one yourself (link has rough instructions) or use some nonlinear regression.